# Async non-polling disposal mechanism to wait until all method calls are finished in .NET 5 C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, synchronization, counter

Often I find my component having a public async (returning `Task<T>`) method `M` and `DisposeCoreAsync`. Other components are using this component by calling `M`. The application runs and at some point the shutdown is invoked. The shutdown is a cascade of disposals on all components. Assume execution of `M` can take a long time. Then the problem arises that when `DisposeCoreAsync` is called, one or more threads are executing `M` and are somewhere in the middle of it. I'd like to find a primitive (or a simple-mechanism) `P`, preferentially using pure .NET 5 libraries, such that I can write something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> M()
{
    if (!P.Increment())
       return false; // Shutdown detected

    ...

    P.Decrement(); // Only after this happens for all active executions, disposal can finish
    return result;
}

protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeCoreAsync()
{
    ...
    P.Shutdown(); // This should prevent new P.Increment to succeed

    await P.WaitAllFinishedAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // From here down we are guaranteed that no thread will ever execute the actual body of M().
    ...
}
```

So `P.Increment` should increment a counter of active executions of M's body. `P.Decrement` decrements the counter. `P.Shutdown` makes sure that any further `P.Increment` attempts fail. `P.WaitAllFinishedAsync` waits until the counter of P goes to 0.

This all is trivial if I allow busy waiting. I can implement `P.Increment` as `Interlocked.Increment`, I can implement `P.Decrement` as `Interlocked.Decrement`, I can implement `P.Shutdown` as `Interlocked.Decrement` with some very high bit, such as 0x1000000. And `P.Increment` succeeds only if after incrementing the new value is positive. Then I can implement `P.WaitAllFinishedAsync` as `while (P.counter > -0x1000000) Task.Delay(10);`

But how to do it properly without `WaitAllFinishedAsync` being a loop periodically checking if we are there yet? Moreover, how to do it with minimal overhead on execution of `M`? It is only shutdown mechanism, so it should not put heavy burden on frequent executions of `M`.

Of course, I'd probably use `using` and make `P.Decrement` inside of `P.Dispose` instead of `P.Increment/Decrement`, to make sure that any exceptions or returns from inside won't forget "freeing" `P`, but that's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Have a `TaskCompletionSource` that you signal from `Decrement()` if the result of the decrement is zero and the shutdown has been requested, and `await` that source from `DisposeCoreAsync()` if the counter is non-zero at the point of the disposal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primitive you're looking for is an async-compatible [countdown event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent). There is no type in the BCL that does this, but you can build one yourself. I have [an open-source one here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/622bc0166067398f5d1d3a8d9cc60b836879a5e8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncCountdownEvent.cs) you can use for inspiration.

Comment: This does not seem to provide ready-to-go Shutdown method, but it is easy to modify, so it will do. Thank you!